# ASP.NET Razor templates editable by users - remove @ for security reasons

Tags: asp.net, razorengine

I made a multi-user blog engine that uses great ASP.NET Razor template engine.

Users are able to edit their page templates and compose them from custom tags like `{{BLOG_POST_NAME}}` `{{BLOG_POST_COMMENTS_LIST}}`

Then those tags `{{...}}` are replaced using regex with appropriate Razor code.

All usage of Razor syntax is done inside those `{{...}}` custom tags that are not editable by users.

So basically user can edit all blog post templates beside custom `{{...}}` tags they are composed from.

What is a good way to restrict Razor syntax in the user defined templates?

I don't want a user to do some `@(ViewModel.Db.DropAllTables())` inside template of blog post, but I must have access to `@(something...)` inside tags that are not editable by users.

As for now, just before user saves template I remove everything `@` from user edited template and then replace tags with their Razor content.

But users can do `@ViewModel.Something` and it still calls Razor logic...

I'm thinking of removing all `@` symbols from user template to prevent it, but it will not allow user to do CSS @media-queries and use email@addresses.com in their template.

Last thing I did - changed regex that finds symbols to delete from user templates to `(@+\B)|(\B@+\b)`

That regex finds `@` to remove from:
'@abc
'@'
@abc
bcd@
abc@(for)

But keeps it for:
abc@abc

Maybe I forgot some other possible usages of Razor @

What can you suggest to do in order to have user-defined templates secured and allow Razor syntax to be used inside tag content only?

Update: RazorEngine is used.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Asp.Net or RazorEngine? You applied both tags to your questions so I'm assuming you are using RazorEngine and answer the question:

I would suggest to allow everything and apply runtime restrictions via code-access-security and an isolated AppDomain (this still has some drawbacks: like users can occupy resources, to fix this you require process level isolation). You can use the RazorEngine Isolation API for this: https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/Isolation.html

In case of Asp.Net you can basically do the same, but you are on your own and need to take care of cross-domain communication yourself.

matthid
 - a RazorEngine contributor

Comment: Yes, it's RazorEngine. AppDomain will protect from accessing the file system. I suppose there is no protection from accessing the database like get a parameter that store connection string and use it with dapper to get MD5 hashes of all users in the system. Thats why I'm thinking on restricting or escaping `@` sign somehow. As for now I just remove `@` after template is submitted by blog user.

Comment: Not completely, you can add your own permissions, make a wrapper class and protect your resources as you like. For example you simply can restrict access to "ViewModel.Db" by making the property SecurityCritical. And the template will not be able to access it.